# Can't reference current div

Tags: javascript, html, this, self

I am having a little problem with "this"...I wanna make the start() works for every div. But like that is returning HTML div obj, you know...

```
function init(){
    box = [];
    box = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    box[i].addEventListener('click', start, false);
}

function start(e,id) {
    e = e || window.e;
    var posX = e.clientX,
    posY = e.clientY;
    console.log(posX,posY);
    //a = this.id;
    a = document.getElementById(this.id);
    alert(a); 
}
```

outside I have two divs:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

When i try logging just "a = this.id" works...Although trying to reference the currente clicked div-id doesnt work with "this"...What did i forget? Please help!

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/saRgf/1/

Comment: why do you wants to do `a = document.getElementById(this.id)`, it gives `a = this`

Comment: Arun that returns obj HTMLDivElement...No? I want to return the id..

Comment: then you  need to do `a = this.id`

Comment: The point of reference it with getElementById is to get attr...like a.style.background

Comment: `getElementById ` will give you a dom reference, then you need to get the attribute from it

Comment: ideas? thats probably very simple and i cant do it...lol

Comment: @user2238744 you are just over complicating a simple requirement

Comment: @user2238744 Honestly I have no idea what your problem is. You can reference the current div just fine, clearly!

Comment: @user2238744 programing is all about simplifying a solution not complicating it

Comment: @user2238744 for the sake of complicating do `a = document.getElementById(this.id).getAttribute('id');`

Comment: Thanks..i just forgot to reference the attr on the alert... alert(a.id);

Comment: lol...thanks arun...i didnt see that... =(

Comment: @user2238744 You already have the ID via `this.id`. You already have the element via `this`. `this` is the same as `a` (in other words, `this === a`) when you do `var a = document.getElementById(this.id)`, and `this.id` is the same as `a.id` as a result. You're going in a circle and winding up exactly where you were in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

It is because `a` is point to a dom object

Try

```
a = document.getElementById(this.id);
alert(a.id);
```

Or

```
a = document.getElementById(this.id);
alert(a.getAttribute('id'));
```